# Open URL in new window from JSP using set of new window attribute

Tags: java, jsp

After processing action class, I have dynamic attribute which needs to be append as query string in static URL like `"https://www.google.co.in/?zipcode="+zipcode"`
I am done till this point. Then I passed control to JSP with URL in request. Now from JSP I want to open this URL in new window with specific new window attributes.

This is I am trying from my jsp :

```
<% 
String redirectURL = (String)request.getAttribute("url2redirect");
response.sendRedirect(%><javascript:openNewWindow()><%
%>
<script> 
function openNewWindow() {
    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    var screenHeight = screen.height;
    var contactUsWidth = screenWidth*90/100;
    var contactUsHeight = screenHeight*90/100;         
window.open('<%=redirectURL%>','appointment','scrollbars,menubar=no,width='+contactUsWidth+',height='+contactUsHeight+',resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,copyhistory=yes,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=0');

}
</script><%);%>
```

Its not working giving syntax error.... Is this the right way ?
How can we open this URL in new window with different window attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call this javascript method from `response.sendRedirect()`?

Doesn't this work?

```
<% 
String redirectURL = (String)request.getAttribute("url2redirect");
%>
<script> 
function openNewWindow() {
    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    var screenHeight = screen.height;
    var contactUsWidth = screenWidth*90/100;
    var contactUsHeight = screenHeight*90/100;         
window.open('<%=redirectURL%>','appointment','scrollbars,menubar=no,width='+contactUsWidth+',height='+contactUsHeight+',resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,copyhistory=yes,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=0');

}
</script>
```

And call `openNewWindow()` from body [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) if you want to load the popup when the page is loaded